# ImageMagic do php não consegue usar o GhostScript para renderizar PDF

Tags: php, osx, permissões, imagemagick

Na minha hospedagem, o ImageMagic renderiza PDF para JPEG normalmente. Mas preciso fazer funcionar no meu MAMP local de testes - fazer sites sem teste local é um saco! O ImageMagic aparentemente está OK no meu MAMP rodando em Mac OS X Lion. O erro aparece da seguinte forma:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'Postscript delegate failed `/Library/WebServer/Documents/www/sintran/apitaco/edicao-03-005-12-2013.pdf': No such file or directory @ error/pdf.c/ReadPDFImage/713' in /Library/WebServer/Documents/www/sintran/conteudo_apitaco_jpeg.php:10
```

No Terminal, testei com "gs /Library/WebServer/Documents/www/sintran/apitaco/edicao-03-005-12-2013.pdf" e o arquivo foi aberto numa janela X11 normalmente. Mas não manjo muito de linha de comando UNIX, e não sei fazer testes mais complexos com o GhostScript.

Após alguma pesquisa, desconfio de problemas de permissões, já que o ImageMagic usa de um aplicativo X11 que está "do lado de fora" do php. Parece que o GhostScript usaria a pasta indicada no php.ini: upload_tmp_dir = /Applications/MAMP/tmp/php. É isso? Esta pasta tem apenas os usuários comuns (Eu, admin e everyone), diferente de outras pastas do sistema (a pasta usr, por exemplo, tem sistema, wheel e everyone), possivelmente o GhostScript não poderia escrever ali. Mas não dá para adicionar um usuário "sistema" pela janelinha de Informações, não aparece na lista de usuários. Como faço isso?

Alguma outra possibilidade?